# How to return string of dict keys in python3 without brackets

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, terminal

I am trying to build an interactive shell-like terminal program in Python3 for a school project.
It should be easily expandable and not rely on non-python-builtin modules.
For this matter, I made a module, which is imported and contains something like this:

```
commandDictionary={
"command":'''
Information for my program on how to handle command
In multiple lines.''',
}
helpDictionary={
"command":'''
Short Text for the help-command to display
Also in multiple lines.'''
}
```

What I want to do is to list all keys from helpDictionaryin a string form if help is input.
The output should look like this:

```
 Help
 List of available commands:
 command1, command2, command3,             command4  #Newline after 4 commands.
 command5, command6, commandWithALongName, command8
```

My Problem is, that helpDictionary.keys() returns something like this:

```
['command1', 'command2']
```

and I dont want the Brackets nor the ' .

Is this possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you unselect my answer after almost a year? Is there something I can improve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to retain the contents in memory, you can print any iterable you want with an arbitrary separator like this:

```
print(*helpDictionary.keys(), sep=', ')
```

If you do want the string for something, use `str.join` on the separator you want:

```
s = ', '.join(helpDictionary.keys())
print(s)
```

Both cases shown above will output the result in essentially arbitrary order because dictionaries use hash tables under the hood. If you want to sort commands lexicographically, replace `helpDictionary.keys()` with `sorted(helpDictionary.keys())`.

Answer (score -1):

So, your problem is how to print a list without brackets. There are several solutions.

1. Traverse the keys: `for k in helpDictionary.keys(): print(k)`
2. Or convert the list to a string, then print the mid.

`li = list(helpDictionary.keys())
print(str(li)[1:-1])`

Comment: your Solution for traversiong the keys is interesting, is it possible to not make a line break every time?

Comment: This is not a very good way. It is inefficient and relies on a particular string representation of a list.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes your solution is better. I have learned from you, thanks.

Comment: I appreciate you saying that. I'm glad my experience is useful to others.